# Adding servers in the client-side dynamically/Runtime

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I am using Consul for Service Discovery; and supply list of servers in NameResolver.start(Listener listener) during Client startup.

1. How can i add new Servers that Joined-in as Service Providers (in Consul)
2. I am using Round Robin; and when one of the server dies; it keeps hitting the dead server
3. Would you have a sample to retry on UNAVAILABLE exception? I just want to retry atleast once before giving up on the Client side.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When the list of servers change (in Consul), call `NameResolver.Listener.onUpdate()`, which you should be calling at least once already.

The load balancing implementations and APIs are receiving a massive rework, which should greatly improve round robin.

Comment: Yes on startup i do NameResolver.Listerner.onUpdate(); but then when Consul state changes; i cannot call NameResolver.Listerner.onUpdate() again because the Listener is nullified by the caller ManagedChannel. I tried keeping the ref of Listner in NameResolver.start(Listener listener) method.

Comment: Only option seems like i will have to write my own Load Balancer; again unfortunately i cannot use TransportManager.updateRetainedTransports() because it has not yet been implemented. All this to avoid Ngnix or other HTTP2 Load balancers in place of gRPC Client side load balancer

Comment: The NameResolver should store the Listener provided during start() as a field, and then call onUpdate() when something changes. I don't understand how another piece of code could null the reference out. This is what is done by the built-in DnsNameResolver.

Comment: @EricAnderson can you public the example code for us.

Comment: @ThamiraLakmal, I don't understand. You can look at the [DnsNameResolver](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/DnsNameResolver.java). It is a bit complex due to blocking DNS queries and some temporary hacks. We don't have any simple example, but in the simple case JavaDocs alone should get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own LoadBalancer; and @Override pickTransport() to RoundRobin healthy gRPC servers from Consul.

Answer (score -1):

In here I use consul as my registry. It works correctly.

It contain both example of Eureka and consul.

https://github.com/WThamira/gRpc-spring-boot-example